# Right way to override magento files

Tags: magento2, overrides

I need to have unicode urls in Magento 2. I have found [this magento issue on github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/653#issuecomment-121831265) that has 4 commits to make it work.

1. I know that directly editing them is a very bad practice. What is the proper way of overriding these files?
2. Is the directory `lib` considered part of the core? (which i am not supposed to edit under any circumstances). If i upgrade magento, will this folder me overwritten?

The file paths are:

```
lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Request/Http.php
lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/TranslitUrl.php
app/code/Magento/Cms/Block/Adminhtml/Page/Edit/Tab/Main.php
app/code/Magento/Cms/Model/ResourceModel/Page.php
```

Also notice that there is no `Magento` directory under `app/code`. Magento code is under `vendor` directory.